# ObservableCollection clears very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` instance with 20 elements in it and set it as `ItemsSource` for a control. When I try to call `Clear()` for this collection, it becomes clean, but after 4-5 seconds of freezing app. If I *don`t use it like value for dependency property* it clears fast. It also doesn't take any time when I *simply run (Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio)* the application instead of debugging.

Never faced with such slowness while working with `ObservableCollection` and don't understand how to fix this(even *while profiling* delay is not shown). I develop control with ItemsSource property, so I can't unassign property value - clear collection - set property value again. My custom control's handlers work fast. And app freezes after Clear() call and before my custom `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event handler called.

Comment: What happens if you set ItemsSource to an empty ObservableCollection<MyClass> instead of Clear? If it's faster then it's probably your CollectionChanged handler, if it's not then it's probably because the View layer of your MyClass VM layer is quite heavy. Your best shot would be to give us some simple working example so we can test on our side

Comment: @nkoniishvt, fixed this with optimization stolen from standard controls, which work fast with ObservableCollection`s, now it works fast. See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, while making your own data grid, I advise for every one to inspect standard wpf controls and how they manage with enumarables. 
In my project while creating cells for my custom grid I did some like this to set collections element as `DataContext` for cell:

```
cellContainer.SetBinding(Grid.DataContextProperty, new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(string.Format("ItemsSource[{0}]", rowIndex)),
    ElementName = "myUserControl"
});
```

It is useless binding, which makes WPF to track changes of collection for every cell and costs much time. Better simply assign item value to `DataContext` of cell container like:

```
cellContainer.DataContext = myUserControlInstance.ItemsSource
    /*.OfType<object>.Skip(rowIndex).FirstOrDefault() or for ILists:*/[rowIndex];
```